# Add a search form in a manyToMany Relation interface

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How to implement a search form in a many to many relation between entities.

I want to search items from an entity before to add them to my other entity. I am using a long list of items (product) that i need to link to Shops and i can't use a simple listbox to select my items.

I need you to point me to a tutorial or any explaination to deal with this interface problem.

The goal is to use a minimum of javascript

Comment: you could use an choice Field Type with the multiple option.

Comment: I have almost 10 000 items... The choice field won't work in this case.
I need to filter the result first to avoid having to much items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent lot's of time trying to figure out the best solution to make the compromise between re-usability, performance and ergonomy and i found a nice solution

I did this way :

- I created a custom form field that show a collection like entity field type but i pass field names that I want to show in a nice table :

  ```
  ->add('products','reflist',array(
               'columns'=>array('name','cost','description'),
               'actions'=>array('select'=>true,'remove'=>true),
               'entityName'=>'VendorProductBundle:Product',
               'searchForm'=> 'Vendor\ProductBundle\Form\ProductSearchType'
        ));
  ```
- Then I created a generic searching service that takes in input the entity to search on. The result is sent in a popup paginated.
- Finally, I created a controller related to my new field to manage actions like add, remove

Thats's it for the logic.

I can't really share the work since it is really dependent of my framework (depend of search service, layout,etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create an view where you could select a category or define your search condition. And a second View where you only display products by the previously selected condition. In your second view you could use an `entity Field Type` ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder ) and provide a custom query for the entities like:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
// ...
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:Product',
    'query_builder' => function(ProductRepository $er) {
       return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                 ->where('p.category = 1);
    },
));
```

This solution doesn't require JavaScript at all.

Comment: It sounds like it's what i am searching. Thanks for your answer. I check it